# Using virtual machines for OS compatibility testing of software

Tags: testing, virtual-machine, compatibility

I need to test a software across different operating systems for compatibility. Is using a virtual machine with different OSs installed a good way to test for compatibility? Is there a repository somewhere where I can use pre-built virtual machines for this?

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably better suited for https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

But yes, using VMs is a good way to scale tests out to multiple platforms and configurations. Unfortunately you won't find a library of images you can just grab and use as you will need licenses for any commercial operating systems and applications installed on the image.